# Is there a way to write a query that returns all child elements without specifying all of the includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In the follow structure is there a way to query Foo and have all the bars returned with all the cats without having to write a query like this: Foo.Include(x => x.bars).ThenInclude(x => x.cats) because there could be more tables below cat that need to be included.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual List<Bar> bars { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual List<Cat> cats { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Cat
{
    public virtual List<N> ...
}
```

I have thought about some sort of recursion to create the includes, but I don't know how to avoid creating circular includes.

Edit:
The purpose for something like this is I need the know which elements are going to be deleted on cascade, so I can store them for a undo mechanism I am writing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed explanation on what the problem is in using `Include()`

Comment: Are you looking for [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)?

Comment: @devlincarnate: I'd say that's the opposite of what OP wants, which is actively loading child entities without having to explicitly `.Include` them.

Comment: @madreflection The opposite of Lazy Loading, I believe, is [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) and the examples in the documentation show `.Include'

Comment: @devlincarnate: Thank you. I was spacing out on the exact term in this case. It's been a long day. Anyway, OP wants eager loading *without* calling `Include` to make it happen. I'm not suggesting that it's a good idea, or that it's even possible without an undue load of reflection... just pointing out that *that's* what they want, not lazy loading.

Comment: @madreflection well, I'm not particularly clear on what the OP wants. Eager Loading requires '.Include'. The opposite of Eager Loading is Lazy Loading. So...that's why I questioned whether the OP wants Lazy Loading.

Comment: @madreflection perhaps the OP should not be using EF then? Raw SQL will achieve the goal of loading related entities without using `.Include`

Comment: Use `AutoInclude`.

Answer (score 0):

The question you should be looking at is really "What data do I want at this time?"

If you are getting a list of Foos and you might want some info from Bars, Cats, Etc. etc. then the best answer is to use projection to create a model, or model hierarchy for the data you want to consume rather than relying on Entities to represent this and debating the hassle of eager loading vs. the cost of lazy loading. For instance when you have a web page displaying a list of items, create a view model, or structure for the fields the view model cares about. From there when you write the Linq query, use `Select` against your "Foo"-based query to extract the fields you care about from each Foo, it's related Bars, Cats, etc. as you need. You can aggregate related data and you don't need to worry about eager vs. lazy loading. EF will build an appropriate query to populate the fields from whatever related tables it needs.

If you are loading a single Foo and expect that conditionally you may end up needing Bars, Cats, etc. then this is a good argument for using Lazy Loading. It will round-trip to the database but only if that related data is referenced. Eager loading for all related entities despite if they will actually be needed is a hassle to write, plus incurs a cost in all cases. When there is a need for a complete object graph then you are generally better off eating the hassle of eager-loading everything, but with EF Core you can leverage `AsSplitQuery` to reduce the performance cost of the resulting Cartesian Product when joining many depths of related collections.

As a general rule when it comes to EF I recommend favoring projection for read operations, whether DTO/ViewModel when passing data back or anonymous types / single values when doing in-place computation.  Only load tracked entities with either eager loading or lazy loading for related data when updating data. It can help to structure you application to work is a more atomic manner where sub-levels can be updated/inserted/deleted as independent actions rather than applying modifications throughout an entire object graph then expecting to update everything through one call with a top-level entity.